# Are there any stresses on this plane in a beam?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, beam

Consider a cantilever beam with a point load at its free end. If we cut the beam through a plane as shown (in which the load lies), to divide the beam into two parts, and if we isolate individual parts, then will there be any stresses on the plane that I point out in the figure?
[image]

Comment: in line with the plane you will have compression and tension from bending.  Perpendicular to the plane you will have the torsional effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Euler's beam theory we don't have transverse stresses.

The cantilever example deforms under the load and deflects but the cross-section remains square (the original shape and size).

But we know (and ignore) that by Hooks law The top of the beam narrows due to the elongation under deformation and the bottom thickens.

So the cross-section will look like a trapezoid, not a square. This transversal deformation increases as the radius of beam deflection decreases (more curvature) near the support. And these strains cause transversal stresses on the cut section you investigate.

On top, we have transversal tension perpendicular to the surface of your half-cut and on the bottom compression stresses.

Comment: Thanks, So if we ignore the change in cross sectional shape and area, the cut plane that I show has no stress?

Comment: that's corret. in engineering we are not seeking the exact solutions, we search for the good enough solutions.

Comment: Kamran, if a point load is applied as shown in the figure on a cantilever beam, won't the vertical layers have a tendency of sliding past each other? The vertical layer of beam on which the point load acts, will try to go down the most and will force neighbouring layers to move down, giving rise to a shear stress in the plane I show.

Comment: As shown in this figure - https://drive.google.com/file/d/10TcdTnoWvd8IdE5hPhgg8p2iGTLxV113/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: If the load were to be distributed along the width of c/s uniformly, all the vertical layers would've gone down by the same amount. Then there wouldn't be any shear stress in the plane I show. But if a point load acts, vertical layers will have a tendency of slipping past each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will be an answer to what you are asking, however when a point in a structure is stressed then at that point there are stresses.

However the stresses will be different depending on the choice of the coordinate system. E.g. if you select the principal axis then there will be no shear stresses. However that doesn't mean that in another coordinate system there are virtually no stresses.

Also you may choose a coordinate system in a plane that has zero normal stresses and a non zero shear stress.

My point being is that:

1. the coordinate system that the streses will be reported needs to be described
2. Stresses is a localised quantity. I.e. different points will have different values and also different principal axis (in the general case).

Comment: Oh right, I need to specify the coordinate system. Actually I was trying to figure out if I take out an element in the beam what will be the stresses on its faces. Consider this for example - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5l38aUjk_RNtKbLerBk2NwZzyPZfU6r/view?usp=sharing , I have taken out an element from within the beam, say above the Neutral Axis, with respect to the x-y system, will the stresses on shaded face and the face opposite to it, will be zero?